# "dirname: invalid option -- '/' " Error when I try to run a .sh file?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I'm trying to run a file in Linux(Ubuntu 14.04), but I get this error:

> dirname: invalid option -- '/'
>      Try 'dirname --help' for more information.

The command I am using to run the .sh file is this:

> ./extract-files.sh

But when I type that (yes, I'm in the directory that it is in), it gives me that error. Help!

Comment: I'd guess the error message refers to something within the script.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Do you want the source code of the script?

Comment: Well, add it to your question if it's not too long (unless it's secret...).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson http://pastebin.com/Vwzvq0dm

Comment: check proprietary-blobs.txt for weird things that dirname seems to call invalid.

Comment: @Rinzwind http://pastebin.com/QLQgYnxJ

Comment: I consider it a BUG. `device/common/generate-blob-lists.sh` generates that text file and it creates lines starting with a `-`; dirname command does not accept these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't try to understand the whole script. But I see that `dirname` is called once, and I suppose that this expression:

```
cat proprietary-blobs.txt | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$ | sed -e 's#^/system/##g'
```

is supposed to generate a list of file paths, while at least one of the elements is not a valid path.

It's easy to trigger the same error message:

```
$ dirname -/
dirname: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
```

---

Inside proprietary-blobs.txt are:

```
-/system/app/OmaDmclient.apk
-/system/app/qcrilmsgtunnel.apk
-/system/app/shutdownlistener.apk
-/system/app/SprintHiddenMenu.apk
-/system/app/TimeService.apk
-/system/app/UpdateSetting.apk
```

All of these error out:

```
dirname -/system/app/OmaDmclient.apk
dirname: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
```

It says

```
This file is generated by device/common/generate-blob-lists.sh - DO NOT EDIT
```

So I consider this a bug in that script.

Comment: Do you need to see the contents of proprietary-blobs.txt?

Comment: yes check it for "-/" That seems to crash dirname; I consider it a bug though!! :) Nice find Gunnar!! :)

Comment: Give me about 30 min-1 hr. Have to get everything setup. Sorry.

Comment: Hope you do not mind that I edit this in ;)

Comment: Fixed it - Someone on Github took all of the LGE devices and uploaded all of the proprietary files. Thanks, anyways!